# Arkham Horror: Is there any thematic introductory text out there for first time players?

Tags: arkham-horror

I'm going to play Arkham tonight with a couple of friends which they don't have any previous Lovecraft experience.

Is there any short text which I could use to introduce them to the Cthulhu Mythos and to what they're about to experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of the investigators has some flavour on the back of their investigator card. I've found using that gives the player some insight in to the strange going ons in Arkham, but leaves them just enough in the dark for it to remain mysterious.

Make sure you read out all the encounter cards and not just get to the business end of things in order to roll dice. Without all the flavour text from the encounters, things can get rather...maddening

Comment: There's also a "Welcome to Arkham!" section at the beginning of the rules, if you feel you need something more general. (Also with reading encounter cards: read them to each other.)

Comment: Never thought of the reading to each other part - that will certainly keep people engaged!